# I can not start with Less. Could you help me to start learn?

Tags: html, variables, less

I try to start with Less but i am not sure what i am doing wrong. It is a very simple example, but i can not see the color that i use in the variable.

Do you have any idea?

[image]

HTML

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Ejemplo1</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.less">
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/less.js/2.7.1/less.min.js"></script>
 </head>

 <body>
  <div class = "num1"></div>
  <div class = "num2"></div>
  <div class = "num3"></div>
 </body>

</html>
```

LESS

```
@color1:red;

div{
 border: solid;
 margin:20px;
}

.num1{
 width: 200px;
 height: 400px;
 background: @color1;
}

.num2{
 width: 400px;
 height: 200px;
 background: @color1;
}

.num3{
 width: 300px;
 height: 300px;
 background: @color1;
}
```

Comment: See http://lesscss.org/#client-side-usage. In short your mistake is in incorrect `<link>` attributes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes! Sorry was maybe a silly question but the answer is:

```
<link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="style.less" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change 'rel' as 'stylesheet/less'. So, final out for Stylesheet linking as,

`<link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="style.less" />`

You can refer more [here](http://lesscss.org/#client-side-usage)